# How many persuade opportunities are in Klurikon?

Tags: achievements, ps3, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

After finishing all side and main quests on the western continent I'm finally in Klurikon. To get the "A Wink and a Smile" trophy I have to succeed at 50 persuation attempts. Unfortunately I don't know how often I already succeeded so I'm curious how many (roughly) opportunities I'll get in Klurikon.

Comment: I couldn't begin to tell you. But throughout the game there are more than enough and there are also a few in the DLC too. I would recommend keeping some persuasion potions on you and saving before you talk to groups of people.

Comment: So there should still be enough if I have like 25/50? Thanks for the tip with the potions.

Comment: The potions can really knock your persuade chances up, I've found a few that I just couldn't do until much later without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall there are nine opportunities.

The list of all persuade opportunities in the main game are listed here (search for `[SKL07]` and then for `klurikon`):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/991142-kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/faqs/63919

I can't paste text here because I think it's against the policy, but if you follow that link you'll get the full list of persuade opportunities in the game

Comment: Nice list thanks. I already finsihed the game and didn't get the trophy but the list is very helpful ^^